# How to generate a 3D sea wave like pattern at time t?

Tags: wave-equation

I'm using the following video background in one of my apps, and am interested in how I can programmatically generate position of a dot on a screen, as in [this animation](http://videohive.net/item/flow-particle-world/7584955).

The way I can describe this animation is as "waves" or "sea", with x,y and t determining the height z. I was going to try to recreate it using two sine waves, but **Is there's a better equation I can use to determine a position of a point on a wave like this at any given time?**

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like the "nodes" of this sea surface are moving rather randomly in $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions, but these lines that connect them are governed by some sort of Bezier curves or maybe even just polynomial interpolation.

Comment: You may like a [related Blender question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14529/).

Comment: Maybe (someone call me out if this is silly) you could superpose some plane waves each with different direction/frequency/wavelength; although these waves by themselves would look monotonously periodic a superposition could give some nice pseudo-random visuals depending on the relation between the respective values of the chosen constants. I guess one downside to this method (if it is plausible/practical) would be the chance to encounter extreme amplitudes if the phases aligned.